# A basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, inner-products

What I want to prove: Suppose $\lambda \in (-\pi,\pi]$ are natural frequencies at time $n$. Then for every $\lambda_j$ define a vector $e_j^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left(e^{i \lambda_j},e^{2i\lambda_j},\ldots,e^{ni\lambda_j}\right)^T$. The $n$ vectors form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$.

$n$ points are called natural frequencies at time $n$: $x_1,\ldots,x_n = \ldots,-\frac{4 \pi}{n}, - \frac{2 \pi}{n},0, \frac{2\pi}{n},\frac{4 \pi}{n},\ldots \subset (-\pi,\pi]$. (The value 0 is always a natural frequency; for odd $n$ there are $(n−1)/2$ positive and negative natural frequencies,
situated symmetrically about 0; for even $n$ the value $\pi$ is a natural frequency, and the
remaining natural frequencies are $n/2 − 1$ points in $(0, \pi)$ and their reflections.)

My attempt: Suppose $j \neq k$ then
\begin{align*}
\langle e_j^n,e_k^n \rangle &= \frac1n \langle e^{i \lambda_j},e^{2i\lambda_j},\ldots, e^{ni\lambda_j} ; e^{i \lambda_k},e^{2i\lambda_k},\ldots, e^{ni\lambda_k} \rangle \\
&= \frac1n \left( e^{i(\lambda_j + \lambda_k)}+\cdots + e^{ni(\lambda_j + \lambda_k)}\right).
\end{align*}
How is this zero? And how do is the length of each $e^n_j$ one as
$$ ||e^n_j|| = \langle e^n_j ; e^n_j \rangle = \frac1n \left( e^{2i \lambda_j} + \cdots +e^{2i n \lambda_j} \right).$$
And lastly how do these vectors span $\mathbb{C}^n$? Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Check the index of your textbook and look for the phrase "natural frequency".  Tell us what definition the text gives.

Comment: Yeah smart, it's: These $n$ points are called natural frequencies at time $n$: $x_1,\ldots,x_n = \ldots,-\frac{4 \pi}{n}, - \frac{2 \pi}{n},0, \frac{2\pi}{n},\frac{4 \pi}{n},\ldots \subset (-\pi,\pi]$. (The value 0 is always a natural frequency; for odd $n$ there are $(n−1)/2$ positive and negative natural frequencies,
situated symmetrically about 0; for even $n$ the value $\pi$ is a natural frequency, and the
remaining natural frequencies are $n/2 − 1$ points in $(0, \pi)$ and their reflections.)

Comment: You've made a mistake with your inner product: note that
$$
\langle x,y \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \overline{y_k}
$$
where the bar denotes the complex conjugate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** note that for any integer $p$,
$$
e^{p\,i \lambda_j - p\,i\lambda_k} = \left( e^{i(\lambda_j - \lambda_k)}\right)^p
$$
In order to compute the inner products, you can use the formula
$$
\sum_{p=0}^{n-1} \xi^p = \frac{\xi^{n} - 1}{\xi - 1}, \quad \xi \neq 0 
$$

Comment: Doesn't the $i$ still needs to be added to the expression? And how does this help me to prove that the norm is 1?

Comment: My mistake with the $i$; see my latest edit.

Comment: The sum helps you do everything *except* show that the norm is $1$.  However, if you calculate the inner product correctly, you should find that it's very easy to show that the norm is $1$.

Comment: Ah yes of course as $\overline{e^{ix}} = e^{-ix}$